# Blender character mesh is moving more than it should?

Tags: modeling, parent

I have a problem with my Created Mesh and my Armature. When I slightly move my bone, almost the whole mesh moves with it..

I created my Mesh using UV Spheres and the Mirror in Editing mode. The bones I also mirrored with Symmetrize (_L at the end of the name).

At the end I checked for the scale and the rotation, I think this shouldn't be the problem, but idk.

It's my first Blender model without any help.

Now, how can I get the stuff right, so that the pose mode works?

https://pasteall.org/blend/2705930f8ac84e82a0be980fce02cd59

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the scale in *Object* mode. Once done, go in *Edit* mode, select all and recalculate the normals.

[image]

Comment: Update: Well, it worked perfectly for me. I just needed to unparent the Body from the armature and then parent it again. Thanks man!